# Upload image from computer to Shopify assets [rails]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, image, shopify-app

I'm developing a Shopify App with rails which modifies the current theme of the merchant's shop.

I'm trying to create a form **to upload an image** (local file from your computer) from the App and **save it directly in the Theme/Assets** .

I've tried with this:

**controller:**

```
 def uploadImage
  if request.post?
    p = ShopifyAPI::Asset.new
    p.key = "assets/image.png"
    p.attach(params[:image])
    p.save
  end
 end
```

**view:**

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadImage">
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">     
       <label>Upload Image</label>
       <input type="file" name="image">            
    <button type="submit" name="button">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[On the documentation page](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/asset), there is not `POST` endpoint, meaning, an asset can't be created by itself, it has to be owned by the theme

The documentation might fail to be complete on that one. Variants could be compared, as they have to be owned by a product; and for this specific part, they do document the `POST /admin/products/#{id}/variants.json` (they should have documented `POST /admin/themes/#{id}/assets.json` for assets)

[You have your solution  in the code source](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/asset.rb#L12), you need to specify the theme id, so this should work :

```
p = ShopifyAPI::Asset.new(key: "assets/image.png", theme_id: _your_theme_id)
p.attach(params[:image])
p.save
```

Haven't tried it, so you might need to save the file locally first, and replace the attach line in your code with the following :

```
p.attach(File.read('local/path/to/your/file.ext'))
```

[see here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/lib/shopify_api/resources/asset.rb#L26)

Comment: @Gyntonic did it helped ?